# how to use variables in the styles used in @Component in angular 2 ? How can I use variable named leftposition in the styles?

Tags: angular

I want to use variable named leftposition and bottomposition of class into styles in @Component. How can I use?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'pdf-RadioButton',
  templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
  styles:[`
    .pdf-radiobutton{
      position:absolute;
      bottom:{{leftposition}} //I want to use this leftposition named variable in the styles
    }
  `]

})
export class RadioButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name:string;
  @Input() leftposition:string;   // value of this variable is coming from tag named <pdf-RadioButton as mentioned in the selector in the @Component
  @Input() bottomposition:string; //this variable contain bottom position for the component

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  radioChanged(message:string){
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngStyle on your Html element as such:

[ngStyle]="{ 'bottom': leftposition }"

Comment: Please explain which Html element you mean and format any code you post as a code block or inline code.